Does legislation on transgender healthcare affect medical researchers?
I have a very simple question that I’m struggling to find an answer for online. Over the last several years, several countries and many states in America have passed legislation that ban medical providers from providing certain treatments to transgender people. There’s a lot of existing writing on the arguments for and against such bans.
One of the arguments that is made in favor of these bans is that there is not enough scientific evidence supporting the use of the treatments. I’m worried that these bans could prevent more research from being conducted. How can the efficacy of a treatment be studied if it can’t be provided? Or are there research carve-outs?
For example, consider the following Tennessee bill. This bill blocks a bunch of different treatments, such as hormone replacement, for minors (except in the case of precocious puberty). I’m not sure if the provisions of the bill have gone into effect yet, as a challenge to the bill has been accepted for review by the US Supreme Court. Nonetheless the bill has been passed.
I’d really appreciate a source for how this kind of medical legislation impacts medical research.

Here's an article that discusses use of randomized controlled trials (RCTs) with gender affirming care: Roles of Randomized Controlled Trials in Establishing Evidence-Based Gender-Affirming Care and Advancing Health Equity
Very few studies of transgender healthcare involve RCTs, where participants are randomized and assigned care for purposes of the study. Instead, most studies are observational, comparing people who did receive a particular treatment compared to those who did not, or looking at the same individuals before and after some type of care. Ethical use of RCTs relies on a range of risk levels and study opportunities that just don't fit very well with gender affirming healthcare.
So, yes, bans on gender affirming care that prevent people from getting a sort care will prevent research on that care, even if there is a carve-out for research.
I would also assume that a research carve-out would involve the researchers taking on all costs associated with the research, which is not necessary with all observational studies where most of the care is paid for as normal standard of care, and the financial burden of research only involves the instruments specifically used for research (for example, the cost of administering questionnaires used to measure participant wellbeing or mental health). Clinical trials for new treatments may have financial backing by companies that stand to profit, but there isn't much profit in treatments that have been standard-of-care for decades so the costs would have to be paid from somewhere else. Unless "somewhere else" is someone swimming in cash, that's going to hurt research.
Localized bans may also paradoxically open a research "opportunity" by creating a forcibly untreated control group (a quasi-experiment), though that would not be an outcome that ethical researchers would ever intentionally seek. However, such studies will also be confounded by the overall environment of support in those political regions that enact such a ban.

Do you know of any sources that discuss this potential impact on research?  Your source is really wonderful for understanding why RCTs aren't the only studies we should be conducting, and it is intuitively clear that healthcare bans would prevent in-state observational studies. But it would be great to have that backed up by medical researchers.  Ultimately I'm looking for support for an argument that trans healthcare bans, as they are written, compromise our ability to find the best and most efficacious therapies and treatments for trans people.

@Joe I will see what I can find, for what it's worth, I am a medical researcher even though I don't study this area, so my answer is mostly coming from familiarity with how "the system" works in terms of funding and such. I suspect most people have focused their energy against these sorts of healthcare bans on the immediate effects on their patients rather than secondary effects on research.

@Joe The section "Questioning the Evidence Base" in the linked source is the part most directly related to questions of research and bans, though I know still not as direct as you're hoping for. The link is that proponents of these bans criticize the lack of RCTs while the field considers most RCT designs unethical.

That makes sense. If you find anything please let me know, but I really appreciate your input. Like I said, I found your linked source to be extremely valuable for me. It’s just not quite direct enough to cite for my purpose.

@Joe Sometimes you need to make an argument by doing the logical work of tying sources together, rather than pointing to someone who already made the precise point you want to make. The latter can even be an illogical argument from authority.

And yes, it makes total sense that people would be much more concerned about the harm this legislation could cause to trans people than the harm to medical researchers.

I agree, but having my deduced concerns echoed by real researchers would lend credence to my argument, not be a fallacious appeal to authority, and would be rhetorically powerful. I’m just trying to make the strongest possible case.
